# Find minimum distribution value for percentage

Tags: uniform-distribution

I need a formula for below requirement. I have a set of users. The user count is dynamic. That is, it can be any number. For Ex, I have 5 users. For each users, I need to distribute the books by the percentage set for the users. For ex:

```
User 1 = 15%
User 2 = 15%
User 3 = 10%
User 4 = 30%
User 5 = 30%
```

The sum of percentage of all users will be 100 always. My question is, we need to get the minimum variation to distribute the books to the users. In my example, the minimum variation is 20. If we have 20 Books, we can share the books as `3, 3, 2, 6, 6`. I need a FORMULA to find this minimum value.
Since I'm very poor in mathematics, I didn't know the correct term.
Here user count and the percentage for each user will vary. Can someone help me to find the formula for the same??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Find the greatest common divisor of the percentages.  In your case it is $5$.  Divide that into each of them to get the number of books to give each one.

Comment: I just wrote an example. Since it is dynamic, it can be any number like `18 17 45 10 10`. So, we can't get a common divisor here.

Comment: Yes you can, the common divisor is $1$.  Give them that many books each.  Are you guaranteed that the percentages are whole numbers?

Comment: The percentage can also be decimal values. It can be any whole or float number

Comment: You need the percentages to be rational.  There is no solution for $\pi\%, (100-\pi )\%$.  The greatest common denominator becomes the least common multiple of the denominators, the number that you need to multiply them all by to get whole numbers.  Then you have the number of books to give each.  It could be large.  It gets harder if you are willing to round a bit (how do you define how much is acceptable) and give people about the right number of books.